# dojo animation on interrupt?

Tags: animation, dojo, interrupt

Is there an equivalent of an 'on interrupt' function when using dojo.fx animations?

On my site, I clear an area by sliding the div off the screen to the left and then clearing the innerHTML. So that the div is available for future use in the same place, I set its final position to be equal to its original position (though it's empty and invisible, so the user doesn't see). I do this by referencing the position when the function is fired to avoid hard coding the position in.

```
function clear (node) {

    // get the current position
    var position = domGeom.position (node, true);

    // slide the calendar off the screen
    var anim = dojo.fx.slideTo ({
        node: node,
        left: -2000,
        unit: "px"
    });

    // attach on onEnd function
    dojo.connect (anim, "onEnd", function (n1, n2) {

        node.innerHTML = "";

        // Reset the node's position
        domStyle.set (node, "left", position.x + "px");
    });

    anim.play();
}
```

The problem is that if the user clicks 'clear' while the function is in progress, for example if they accidentally double click, then the 'position' variable takes the value of the node mid-animation. If I later put some content in the node, it's in the wrong place, or sometimes completely off screen.

What I was thinking of doing was adding a listener to the animation so that if it was ever interrupted, it would stop the animation and instead execute the 'onEnd' function immediately, so that the second clear function would have the correct position variable.

Unfortunately, I can't find such a listener; could anyone point me in the right direction, or suggest an alternative solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might be interrupting the flow of events in your page, but you're not really 'interrupting' in Animation terms: there's no way an Animation could give you an event to tell you that Clear has been pressed, I'm afraid.

If you want the animation to be stopped when the user presses Clear, you'll have to stop the animation manually when the user presses Clear: Dojo can't automatically detect there's any link between the two things, and indeed there may well be other animations that you want to continue even if the user does press Clear.

So, you'll probably be looking to call [.stop](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dojo/_base/fx.html#stop) on the animation when appropriate.

Comment: I was afraid of something like that... Given that it's called by an onclick event, there's no way of me passing the anim variable that is currently playing to the function so that it can be stopped before the new animation starts. Thank you any way :)

Comment: Yes there is. Normal JavaScript closure scoping rules apply. So, for instance, in the code sample from the original question, the inner function you pass to connect is closed over the the variable context from inside the 'clear' function, so in that example, for instance, you have access to both `position` and `clear`.  It's definitely not the case that you can't access anything from inside an event callback!